# How can I extend an existing windows mobile app to work with devices with different screen sizes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I've inherited an existing windows mobile app that was designed for a touchscreen landscape device but now I need to extend it to work on a smaller resolution portrait device.  The setup of the solution (vs2008) is as follows:

- Helpers Project
- User Controls Project
- Main Program Project

Helpers has some shared code such as DB connections, error reporting, custom objects etc. User Controls has custom buttons, custom keypad/numpad etc. Main Program is where the bulk of the code is with one base form and several user controls that act as pages. The 'pages' are shown/hidden as needed.

What i'd like is advice on how to make this work for a second (portrait) device and for that matter, any other devices that might come along in future.

My initial thought was to move all the business logic, that can be shared, from Main Program into Helpers and then add a Main Program (portrait) Project with redesigned Forms and User Controls (pages) for the smaller screen. That way, the landscape and portrait projects could be deployed independently.

When I tried this however I couldn't get access to the main program base form from the helpers. VS wouldn't allow me to add a reference into helpers for main program. I'm guessing this is due to circular referencing. Is there a way I could do this so that I could pass landscape/portrait and a form name as parameters to know what project to target? The portrait version will function in exactly the same way but just shown on a smaller screen.

Another thought was to resize the form and user controls on the fly when a smaller screen is detected but that seemed long winded and clunky. I don't think that using anchoring and docking is an option because simply showing a smaller version of the landscape forms would ruin the usability on a portrait device.

I've tried to make this question as short as possible but if you need any more information just ask. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on whether or not the original developer buried lots of business logic in his forms or not.  The more logic in them, the more effort you've got to put in to solve this.

Personally, I often code my business logic is separate controller classes that have a reference to an Interface (instead of a form or full-screen UserControl) that has the required properties and events needed.  Then in entirely separate projects (one for each device layout) I create my screens and implement the UI interfaces.  This appraoch allows you to add devices very easily.

If you have a ton of logic in the forms another version of this is to turn all of your forms into base classes such that all your code and even event handlers residethere.  Make your controls available to subclasses by marking them protected or having the base class provide virtual methods to access them.  Then in each device-specific UI project you inherit from the base forms.

In both approaches, your satellite UI projects references the one with the base classes.  You break the circular reference, and achieve runtime loading of just the UI you want, via a concept people call nowadays inversion of control, but it really is just dynamically loading your types.  Personally I have been using a simple config file for this and a simple utility class for ages and it works fine.  Here's my loader class.  In looking at this, you could also use generics to get rid of the `derivesFrom` parameter and avoid a cast, but this will get you started:

```
public static class ObjectLoader
{
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// public static methods
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

public static object LoadFromAssembly(
    string srcAssembly,
    string typeName,
    Type derivesFrom)
{
    return LoadFromAssembly(srcAssembly, typeName, derivesFrom, true);
}

public static object LoadFromAssembly(
    string srcAssembly,
    string typeName,
    Type derivesFrom, 
    bool throwOnLoadError)
{

    if (srcAssembly == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("srcAssembly");
    else if (srcAssembly.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Value may not be empty.", "srcAssembly");
    else if (typeName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("typeName");
    else if (typeName.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Value may not be empty.", "typeName");
    else if (derivesFrom == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("derivesFrom");

    object retVal = null;

    try
    {
        string srcAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(AppDir, srcAssembly);
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(srcAssemblyPath);
        object obj = asm.CreateInstance(typeName);

        if (obj != null && derivesFrom.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        {
            retVal = obj;
        }
        else if (obj != null) // wrong object, cleanup as needed
        {
            if (obj is IDisposable)
                ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (throwOnLoadError)
            throw;
        // otherwise null is returned...
    }

    return retVal;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// private static methods
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

private static string AppDir
{
    get
    {

        string appFullPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(appFullPath);
    }
}

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply tcarvin and for providing your loader class. I've not used this approach before so i'll go away and see if I can implement it. I will report back.

Oh, and yes i'd say 80% of the business logic is buried in the forms  *sigh* hey ho, it will be worth it in the end as I've just found out that more devices will be introduced later in the year.

Comment: Post back your feedback or questions after you've had a chance to play around with it all.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks tcarvin I went for the base class approach and have resolved my problem. It took a while because of the amount of business logic to separate. Now, adding extra UIs will involve minimal copying and pasting.